# language design: implicit conversions when comparing two values

Tags: language-design

With a friend, we are making a new language called Simp. It should be a simple but modern scripting language with nice and intuitive syntax. Here is a short example:

```
var sum = 0
for i in 3..999 {
    if (i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0) {
         sum += i
    }
}
say sum
```

Now we are standing against a problem if we should use implicit conversions when comparing two values. Specifically, what should the following program output?

```
# 1.
say (1 == '1')

# 2.
var x = 1
switch (x) {
    case '1': say true; break;
    case 1: say false; break;
}

# 3.
if ('1') say true;
else say false;
```

If `1.` outputs true, we should probably also include `===` operator that checks the types too. But I am not a big fan of that operator.

If it throws an error because two different types are compared, that is fine. A bit more typing (`1 == int('1')`) solves the issue and makes the code clearer. But in that case, how to behave for `2.` and `3.`?

What solution do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very subjective. If everyone on this site answered this question every answer would be different. Depends what you want. It seems like you're making a new language as a learning experience, rather than to solve some percieved problem with existing languages. Nothing wrong with that, but you're going to run into this "what do you think this should mean?" problem a lot if you don't set some sort of goal.

Paul Graham advocates the philosophy that the best design comes from designing for yourself. The C programming language was popular because the inventors designed it for themselves first, rather than others. Incidentally this made it popular with others. On the other hand, COBOL was designed by a commitee so that non-programmers could understand it and programmers could use it. In the end non-programmers still couldn't read it and programmers hated using it.

With that in mind, set the goal of making a language that feels right for you, and don't place too much weight on other people's opinions. If after making certain design decisions you have a language that you don't enjoy using, ask yourself why and make the necessary changes until you do enjoy using it.

In this particular example, you say you don't like the === operator. Then don't include it.

It might be beneficial for you to investigate other paradigms if you haven't already. The depth and conceptual quality present in popular imperative/Object oriented languages can be quite limiting. Not saying there isn't much depth, just that by basing everything on what you know from those paradigms, you'd be restricting yourself to an extremely small subset of concepts you could include in this new language.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. We will probably make `==` to check types as well. But simply `if (x) {}` will perform implicit conversion (to bool) on `x` and things like `"", [], 0` evaluates to false. Hence, `if (x) {}` is going to be less strict than `if (x == true) {} `, which make sense cause less explicit usually means less strict. Maybe, we will also get rid of `{}` parentheses but that is another story :-).

Comment: Btw. me and my friend, we both love haskell! And it is going to be noticeable :-). I think we are close to something really cool. Please, keep your fingers crossed for us :-).

Comment: Haha, sure! Good to know that you're still working on this. Will look forward to seeing what comes of it